# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException with Android 11

Tags: java, android, ssl, curl, openssl

My app throws an javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException error when trying to connect to my server using HTTPS on Android 11. All is fine on prior versions of Android.

What could be causing this? I'm using a Full SSL through CloudFlare. Does Android 11 require a Full SSL (strict)?

```
2020-09-12 19:21:37.131 20726-20857/? I/APP: I 09/12/2020 19:21:37:130 b7ef51e0 Net| POST request (Pull): sync.mydomain.com/rc/v1/app/login
2020-09-12 19:21:37.146 206-212/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
2020-09-12 19:21:37.149 206-212/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
2020-09-12 19:21:37.143 206-206/? W/Binder:206_2: type=1400 audit(0.0:3377): avc: denied { read } for name="wakeup34" dev="sysfs" ino=18474 scontext=u:r:system_suspend:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2020-09-12 19:21:37.147 206-206/? W/Binder:206_2: type=1400 audit(0.0:3378): avc: denied { read } for name="wakeup35" dev="sysfs" ino=18534 scontext=u:r:system_suspend:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2020-09-12 19:21:37.192 20726-20857/? I/APP: I 09/12/2020 19:21:37:192 b7ef51e0 SSLImplJava| SSL connect to sync.mydomain.com:443
2020-09-12 19:21:37.192 20726-20857/? I/APP: I 09/12/2020 19:21:37:192 b7ef51e0 SSLImplJava| Creating secure SSL factory
2020-09-12 19:21:37.193 20726-20857/? I/APP: I 09/12/2020 19:21:37:193 b7ef51e0 SSLImplJava| Creating TrustManager for system certificates
2020-09-12 19:21:37.193 20726-20857/? I/APP: I 09/12/2020 19:21:37:193 b7ef51e0 SSLImplJava| Loading all SSL certificates from config
2020-09-12 19:21:37.193 20726-20857/? I/APP: I 09/12/2020 19:21:37:193 b7ef51e0 SSLImplJava| SSL certificates loaded: 0
2020-09-12 19:21:37.193 20726-20857/? I/APP: I 09/12/2020 19:21:37:193 b7ef51e0 SSLImplJava| Creating TrustManager for custom certificates
2020-09-12 19:21:37.193 20726-20857/? I/APP: I 09/12/2020 19:21:37:193 b7ef51e0 SSLImplJava| clientSSLCertificate is
2020-09-12 19:21:37.195 20726-20857/? I/APP: I 09/12/2020 19:21:37:195 b7ef51e0 SSLImplJava| Secure SSL factory initialization completed
2020-09-12 19:21:37.196 20726-20857/? I/APP: E 09/12/2020 19:21:37:196 b7ef51e0 SSLImplJava| Call of "connect" failed: SSLHandshakeException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.OutputStream.write(byte[], int, int)' on a null object reference
2020-09-12 19:21:37.197 20726-20857/? W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.OutputStream.write(byte[], int, int)' on a null object reference
2020-09-12 19:21:37.197 20726-20857/? W/System.err: at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLUtils.toSSLHandshakeException(SSLUtils.java:362)
2020-09-12 19:21:37.197 20726-20857/? W/System.err: at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.doHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:276)
2020-09-12 19:21:37.197 20726-20857/? W/System.err: at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:217)
2020-09-12 19:21:37.197 20726-20857/? W/System.err: at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.waitForHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:563)
2020-09-12 19:21:37.197 20726-20857/? W/System.err: at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.getOutputStream(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:298)
2020-09-12 19:21:37.197 20726-20857/? W/System.err: at com.rhomobile.rhodes.socket.SSLImpl.connect(SSLImpl.java:639)
2020-09-12 19:21:37.197 20726-20857/? W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.OutputStream.write(byte[], int, int)' on a null object reference
2020-09-12 19:21:37.197 20726-20857/? W/System.err: at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLOutputStream.writeToSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:715)
2020-09-12 19:21:37.197 20726-20857/? W/System.err: at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLOutputStream.writeInternal(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:689)
2020-09-12 19:21:37.197 20726-20857/? W/System.err: at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLOutputStream.access$200(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:616)
2020-09-12 19:21:37.197 20726-20857/? W/System.err: at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.doHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:245)
2020-09-12 19:21:37.197 20726-20857/? W/System.err: ... 4 more
2020-09-12 19:21:37.197 20726-20857/? I/APP: E 09/12/2020 19:21:37:197 b7ef51e0 Net| Operation finished with error 35: SSL connect error
2020-09-12 19:21:37.197 20726-20857/? I/APP: E 09/12/2020 19:21:37:197 b7ef51e0 Net| CURLNetRequest: METHOD = [POST] URL = [https://sync.mydomain.com/rc/v1/app/login] BODY = [{"login":"","password":"","remember_me":1}]
```

Comment: Check the the cert is valid, may be you can check from browser.

Comment: It works in browser in Android 11.

Comment: is that the URL you are trying to hit https://sync.mydomain.com/rc/v1/app/login?

Comment: Which library you are using for calling the URL? Can you put a code sample which reproduces this error?

Comment: My app is using Rhodes. The SSL implementation is located here: https://github.com/rhomobile/rhodes/blob/7-2-stable/platform/android/Rhodes/src/com/rhomobile/rhodes/socket/SSLImpl.java

Comment: Here is something to check https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/behavior-changes-all#ssl-sockets-conscrypt.

Comment: This issue has been reported on github https://github.com/rhomobile/rhodes/issues/1051